# What does the text on this jacket say?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, words, sentence

[image: Spirit Blossom Thresh Premium Gi Bomber Graphic]

Do the two blurbs of text detailed below say something like:

-"Pitiful and lost serene soul(s)"
-"Jailer of Chains"

I've tried to zoom in on this image to decipher the text to the right of the center of the mask. It's unfortunately not high resolution enough to easily make sense of it, but my best guess based on the context of the character this art is tied to is:

晴朗なさまよう哀れな魂よ

I'm guessing from some research that this is the translation they made for a voice line where the character says "Poor lost souls." But it seems like in that case they have added some meaning through localization or whatever the process may have been.

I'm reasonably sure there's probably not much else it could be, but due to the fact that Riot Games/League of Legends is not a Japanese company/game and the Japanese stuff they have put out here and there before has generally just been character names, I'm unsure if the Japanese they've used is odd or not and so therefore could be something else due to strange translation of the source English material.

On the front of the jacket it also says:

縛鎖の看守

From what I've been able to find, the first two characters are not a real compound word and are probably a made up thing for the purposes of the game and its fantasy themes and vocabulary; how would it be read? ばくさ? It's most likely a translation of the character's title, "The Chain Warden."

I guess as a follow-up question, assuming that the source English I found is indeed what the Japanese blurbs are translations of, is this accurate/natural sounding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

晴朗 doesn't seem to fit the atmosphere of this image. The tiny text is probably **暗闇を**さまよう哀れな魂よ ("O the wretched souls wandering **in the darkness**"), but I'm not 100% certain about the 暗闇 part.

I don't know the game, but I think 縛鎖の看守 is a good possible translation of "The Chain Warden." This 縛鎖 is just another "cool fantasy term" used by several fictional works. It doesn't have a strict definition, but it does sound somewhat deep or mysterious than simple 鎖. It's almost certainly read ばくさ if there is no furigana.